# What did I miss trying to send query from Angular to my localhost?

Tags: angular, api, express, graphql

I was trying to solve this error for the whole evening already but have no luck with that.

***Error:*** ERROR Error: Network error: Converting circular structure to JSON

I've run through a huge number of articles, followed each step but it doesn't work for me anyway. 
I thought maybe that's because I didn't use cors on the express server but it didn't help anyway.

I would be glad for any help.

My code for angular:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLinkModule, HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const uri = 'http://localhost:8080/graphql'; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule { }
```

functions where I am trying to send my query:

```
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';


signUpSubmit() {


    if (this.signUpForm.status === 'VALID') {
      // console.log(this.signUpForm.get('email').value);

      const user = {
        email: this.signUpForm.get('email'),
        password: this.signUpForm.get('password')
      };

      this.sendData(user);

    } else {

      console.log('Invalid form');
    }
  }

  private sendData(user) {
    this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: gql`
        mutation addUser($email: String, $password: String) {
          addUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
            email
            password
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: user
    }).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

API code

```
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema, gql } from "apollo-server-express";
import * as mongoClient from "./config";
import cors from 'cors';

import User from './models/User'

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const typeDefs = gql`

    type User {
        email: String
        password: String
    }

    type Author {
        id: Int!
        firstName: String
        lastName: String
        books: [Book]
    }  

    type Book {
        title: String
        author: Author
    }

    type Query {
        author: Author
        authors: Author
        book: Book
        books: [Book]
    } 

    type Mutation {
        addUser(email: String, password: String): User
    }

    schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
  }

`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        authors: (obj, args, context, info) => {
            return "console.log()";
        },
        books: (obj, args, context, info) => {
            return `Here you've got the list of books!`;
        }
    },

    Mutation: {
        addUser: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
            try {
                const res = await User.create(args);
                return res;
            } catch (err) {
                return err.message;
            }
        }
    }
};

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: typeDefs,
    resolvers: resolvers
});

// Build Apollo server
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema });
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

// Run server
app.listen({ port }, () => {
    console.log(
        `Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`
    );
});
```

Comment: `http://localhost^8080` isn't the right way to specify a port in url..

Comment: @Eldar oh, sorry it’s a typo. I tried many ways already and made a mistake here. I used : but it doesn’t work anyway

Comment: @Eldar I believe the solution is very simple and funny here but I am not really familiar with this stuff yet so I skimmed over a lot of articles but it didn’t work. There are no much information for graphql and Angular

Comment: @Eldar can it be because ports are different?

Comment: I don't think it is network related. There is something either how you send the data or the server tries to resolve it. First try removing  `books: [Book]` from author type. second initialize your model like this. `const user = {
        email$: this.signUpForm.get('email'),
        password$: this.signUpForm.get('password')
      };`

Comment: @Eldar it doesn’t reach the server. I tied to console.log anything but it didn’t. I thought on that too. It’s something with angular. Graphql works via its interface “playground”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is these lines :

```
 const user = {
    email: this.signUpForm.get('email'),
    password: this.signUpForm.get('password')
  };
```

`FormControl.get()` method returns an `AbstractControl` which is complex and has recursive properties. So your apollo client tries to resolve it and fails..
You need to get values not controls.

```
const user = {
    email$: this.signUpForm.get('email').value,
    password$: this.signUpForm.get('password').value
  };
```

And as i mentioned in the comments your property names should be the same with your mutation definition.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot for your help! Could you also recommend any good technique to split up the schema?

Comment: @Valaryo i use different backend technologies (.net core). We also have the same problem there. We made our workaround to creating empty types to group related queries. So in your example our root query had queries Book and Author they werent actual queries but paths to the queries. There is a good article about organizing graphql schema : [here](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-schema-stitching-explained-schema-delegation-4c6caf468405#schema-binding-an-easy-way-to-reuse-graphql-apis)

Comment: on the internet I found a few techniques, and schema_merge or something like this from Apollo, but it’s deprecated already. Do you use .graphql file extension in your project?

Comment: @Valaryo yes but only for client side and its for only schema definition to write queries. And use `gql` to define queries. Server side has concrete classes for defining types and schema.